# Populating multiple plotly offline plots<div> of HTML page using flask

Tags: html, flask, plotly

I am trying to embed multiple plotly offline plots into an HTML page at different locations on the page. I am using flask at the back-end. Currently I am unable to change the properties of the  returned by plotly offline plot to change the location, width, height on the HTML page. I am new to the front-end development concept so pardon my ignorance.

I am using the below test code to create div plot.

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go


def plot_test():
    months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
    user = [10,50,30]
    t20h = [17, 46, 39]


    trace1 = go.Scatter(x= months, y=user, mode='lines+markers', name="OHR")
    trace2 = go.Scatter(x= months, y=t20h, mode='lines+markers', name="T20H")
    data = [trace1, trace2]

    layout = go.Layout(title='Test', xaxis=dict(title='Months'), yaxis=dict(title='Test'))
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    div_output = plot(fig, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs=False)

    return div
```

And below code to render the results in my HTML

```
from plot_test import plot_test

@app.route('/')
def home():
    plotly_graph = plot_test()
    return render_template("index.html", plotly_graph=Markup(plotly_graph))
```

And below is my HTML. Currently the plot gets crated but at the top of everything else. All my other buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Intro</title>
        <link href="static/index_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="home">
            <form action="/" method="GET">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default>" value="HOME" id="home-btn">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="logout">
            <form action="/logout" method="GET">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default>" value="LOGOUT" id="logout-btn">
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
        {{ plotly_graph }}
        <!-- errors -->
        <!-- {% if error %}
            <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}</p>
        {% endif %}
         -->
        <!-- messages -->
        <!-- {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
            {{ message }}
        {% endfor %} -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your CSS stylesheet?

Comment: @smundlay , I haven't added anything with respect to plotly graph in my css..

Answer (score 0):

I used a slightly different approach :

(simplified)

- In my python code, I returned fig instead of the plot itself
- In the HTML, I created a div with id( 'div_name'
- In Javascript, through the API call received the data to recreate the plot
  and then I only had to add Javascript: Plotly.plot("div_name",fig[("data],fig["layout"].

This way you have more flexibility trying out different sizing methods for either your div or the width-height arguments of the layout itself.

Comment: Hi Fabrice, Thanks for the suggestion would it be possible for you to post the code for same. I am naive to HTML coding so examples would help.